# mysql next and previous

Tags: php, mysql

I currently am using mysql and php to display 9 random results from my table of about 1100 records.

Would it be possible to have a next and previous button even though it's random? I looked at a couple of the examples already posted here but they seem to be application/project specific. Here is what my code looks like..

```
    function executeQuery($searchKey)
    {

        if ($searchKey == null)
        {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT flightNumber, flightCity FROM allFlights LIMIT 0,9";
        //DEBUG -echo "<p>$searchKey</p>";echo "<p>$query</p>";
        }
        else
        {
        //DEBUG -echo "<p>$searchKey</p>";echo "<p>var not null</p>";
           $query = "Select distinct * from allFlights where flightCity LIKE '%$searchKey%' LIMIT 0,9";
        //DEBUG -echo "<p>$searchKey</p>";echo "<p>$query</p>";
        }
   $result=mysql_query($query);
   $numrow=mysql_numrows($result);
   if ($numrow === 0)
   {
    $query = "Select distinct * from allFlights where flightNumber LIKE '%$searchKey%' LIMIT 0,9";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $numrow=mysql_numrows($result);
   }
return $result;
     }

       function populate ()
       {
         $searchKey = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]); //assigns user input to searchKey variable
         //DEBUG -echo "<p>$searchKey</p>";
         $result=executeQuery($searchKey);
         $numrow=mysql_numrows($result);

     if ($numrow == 0)
     {
        echo "<center><p><b> No results found, please try another keyword.</p></center></b>";
     }
     else
     { display results. -- this part i have working.
             }
```

I prefer upon loading the page this happens:
-The current position with respect to the # of flights available are listed. (Now showing 9 of 1100 flights)
-9 random flights are displayed.
-Next button that will show the next 9 flights (random would be nice.)
-Previous button that will show the previous(original) 9 flights (random would be nice.)

When all is said and done I would like to be able to load the page identify the 9 random flights, press next identify the new 9 random flights, then previous and identify the original 9 random flights.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: please review your formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ORDER BY RAND(seed) to give a [pseudorandom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) order that is repeatable:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ....
ORDER BY RAND(9325)
LIMIT 99, 9
```

Adjust the offset to move back and forwards through the results. The seed can be any integer, and you can change it if you want to re-randomize the order, but you **must** use the same seed when pressing back or forward.

Comment: I understand and can get the random part to work, but i do not understand how to adjust the offset for next/previous. My first thought was to select * and assign the total number of rows to a count variable and just increment/decrement depending on what button is pressed. If there is not a better way then that is what I'll end up having to do.

Comment: @snapplex: You might also want to look at [FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).